# /proc/self/maps write memory to file using fwrite bad address error

Tags: linux, memory, fwrite, memory-address, proc

I try to write memory into a file, using fwrite, but it get "bad address". I don't know the reason.

The code is showed below

```
static struct MmapHeader* mmap_headers[HEADER_MAX];

struct MmapHeader
{
    bool isContext; // used to mark the end of maps
    size_t start; //process memory start address
    size_t len; // process memory size
    int prot; // permission
    size_t offset; //offset
    char file_name[FILE_NAME_MAX]; //file name
};

for(i=0;mmap_headers[i]!=NULL;i++)
{
    if(mmap_headers[i]->prot & PROT_READ)
    {
        printf("save map information start:%zx,len:%zx\n",mmap_headers[i]->start,mmap_headers[i]->len);
        if(fwrite(mmap_headers[i],sizeof(struct MmapHeader),1,save_file)<1)
            perror("following error occur:");
        fflush(save_file);
        //******
        //error is in fwrite below, mmap_headers[i]->start is the address of
        //memory, the address is read from file /proc/self/maps the value is
        //7ffea6de4000(hex), the mmap_headers[i]->len is 2000(hex). 
        if(fwrite((void*)mmap_headers[i]->start,mmap_headers[i]->len,1,save_file)<1)
            perror("following error occur:");//here is "bad address error only for address 7ffea6de4000(hex)"
        fflush(save_file);
    }
}
```

output is:

```
save map information start:400000,len:c1000
save map information start:6c0000,len:3000
save map information start:6c3000,len:3000
save map information start:1921000,len:23000
save map information start:2b7d46805000,len:2000
save map information start:7ffea6dc3000,len:21000
save map information start:7ffea6de4000,len:2000
following error occur:: Bad address
save map information start:7ffea6de6000,len:200
```

mmap_headers store the process information read from file /proc/self/maps, size of mmap_headers is 8, other 7 address write successfully except for address 7ffea6de4000(hex), does someone has a idea?

Comment: Does your function that reads `/proc/self/maps` allocate 0x2000 bytes of memory before opening the file, and then free it before you run this code fragment?  If you used stdio to read that file, it's probably the IO buffer, and is freed when you close the file.  Lucky for you, `sys_write(2)` returns `-EFAULT` instead of actually segfaulting when you pass it a bad address, so `fwrite(3)` can return an error instead of segfaulting.

Answer (score 0):

"Bad Address" corresponds to the error code `EFAULT`. If you read the manual page for the underlying system call, `man 2 write`, you will find this description of the error:

```
EFAULT buf is outside your accessible address space.
```

This means that the address you have passed to `fwrite` (and thus to `write`) is not valid.

If you run `cat /proc/self/maps`, you can see that even in a program like `cat`, there are unreadable pages:

```
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 00:11 6447384                            /usr/bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 00:11 6447384                            /usr/bin/cat
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 00:11 6447384                            /usr/bin/cat
0060d000-0062e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
34ddd837000-34dddba0000 r--p 00000000 00:11 6755848                      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
34dddba0000-34dddd3b000 r-xp 00000000 00:11 6904408                      /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
34dddd3b000-34dddf3a000 ---p 0019b000 00:11 6904408                      /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
34dddf3a000-34dddf3e000 r--p 0019a000 00:11 6904408                      /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
34dddf3e000-34dddf40000 rw-p 0019e000 00:11 6904408                      /usr/lib/libc-2.22.so
34dddf40000-34dddf44000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
34dddf44000-34dddf66000 r-xp 00000000 00:11 6904407                      /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so
34dde119000-34dde11c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
34dde13f000-34dde161000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
34dde161000-34dde163000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                            [vvar]
34dde163000-34dde165000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                            [vdso]
34dde165000-34dde166000 r--p 00021000 00:11 6904407                      /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so
34dde166000-34dde167000 rw-p 00022000 00:11 6904407                      /usr/lib/ld-2.22.so
34dde167000-34dde168000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3fd669db000-3fd669fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                            [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Here the second page belonging to `libc` is not readable by the program. If the program tried to pass this as an argument to the `write` system call, it would not succeed and I suspect that is exactly what's happening in your code.

Comment: I think the OP's `if(mmap_headers[i]->prot & PROT_READ)` catches those unreadable regions.  I still like my I/O buffer theory, that the EFAULT is from memory that was unmapped between when the file was read and when this function runs.

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds more likely. I missed that the statement was guarding against unreadable pages.